# Continous Error 1045 (28000) : Access denied for user 'myadmin'@'192.168.1.32' Centos 7

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7

I'm not even sure where to begin.  I'm having an issue remotely connecting to my MariaDB server Centos 7 Server.  I installed MariaDB version 10.4.17 on server 1 (192.168.1.34)

```
mariadb -v
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 11
Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Reading history-file /root/.mysql_history
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

This is my mariadb settings on my db server 1.
/etc/my.cnf.d

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
#[mysqld]
[mysqld_safe]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log

[mysqld]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
#bind-address = 0.0.0.0

skip-networking=0
#skip-bind-address

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mariadb_error.log
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.4 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.4]
```

Here's my user list for mariadb on server 1.

```
SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;


+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| User        | Host         | plugin                |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| mariadb.sys | localhost    | mysql_native_password |
| root        | localhost    | mysql_native_password |
| mysql       | localhost    | mysql_native_password |
| mytracker   | localhost    | mysql_native_password |
| myadmin     | 192.168.1.32 | mysql_native_password |
| mytracker   | 192.168.1.32 | mysql_native_password |
| mytracker   | 192.168.1.33 | mysql_native_password |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Here is the list of all the plugins in MariaDB.

```
SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS;
+-------------------------------+---------------+
| PLUGIN_NAME                   | PLUGIN_STATUS |
+-------------------------------+---------------+
| binlog                        | ACTIVE        |
| mysql_native_password         | ACTIVE        |
| mysql_old_password            | ACTIVE        |
| wsrep                         | ACTIVE        |
| CSV                           | ACTIVE        |
| MEMORY                        | ACTIVE        |
| Aria                          | ACTIVE        |
| MyISAM                        | ACTIVE        |
| MRG_MyISAM                    | ACTIVE        |
| CLIENT_STATISTICS             | ACTIVE        |
| INDEX_STATISTICS              | ACTIVE        |
| TABLE_STATISTICS              | ACTIVE        |
| USER_STATISTICS               | ACTIVE        |
| SQL_SEQUENCE                  | ACTIVE        |
| InnoDB                        | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_TRX                    | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_LOCKS                  | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_LOCK_WAITS             | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_CMP                    | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_CMP_RESET              | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_CMPMEM                 | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET           | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX          | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET    | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE            | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU        | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS      | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_METRICS                | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD    | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_FT_DELETED             | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED       | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_FT_CONFIG              | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE         | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE         | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_TABLES             | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS         | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_INDEXES            | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS            | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_FIELDS             | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN            | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS       | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES        | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES          | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL            | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_MUTEXES                | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_SYS_SEMAPHORE_WAITS    | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_TABLESPACES_ENCRYPTION | ACTIVE        |
| INNODB_TABLESPACES_SCRUBBING  | ACTIVE        |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA            | ACTIVE        |
| SEQUENCE                      | ACTIVE        |
| unix_socket                   | ACTIVE        |
| FEEDBACK                      | DISABLED      |
| user_variables                | ACTIVE        |
| partition                     | ACTIVE        |
+-------------------------------+---------------+
54 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

So, when I go to server 2 to do remote client connection here's the error:

```
[root@server2 ~]# mysql --host=192.168.1.34 --user=myadmin --password=’**********’ -P3306

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myadmin'@'192.168.1.32' (using password: YES)
[root@wp2 ~]#
```

Here is my setting for secure installation.

```
mysql_secure_installation

enter current password for root   HIT ENTER since root password doesn’t exist yet.

switch to Unix_socket authentication  N

change the root password: Y
New password: *****************
Re-enter new password: *****************
Remove anonymous users:  Y

Disallow root login remotely:  n

Remove test database and access to it:  Y

Reload privilege tables now:  y
```

I had tried turning the Unix_socket authentication on and off and it's giving me the same problem.  I dig everywhere and I can't seem to find the working solution.  I tried the auth_socket.so route as well but I can't seem to find the so file anywhere.  Is there a trick that I need to know that you can share in order for me to connect to my MariaDB server remotely?  I'm stumped.  Please help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's happening but it now just seems to work.  I can now connect.  I can't explain why or what.  I'm guessing my setup is working as is.  Hope that setup above will help future users who may have encountered the problem I was facing.